# Find files with "^M"

Tags: php, linux, grep, find, special-characters

I've `^M` somewhere at the beginning of one of my php files and I can't find where it is. this causes all my pages start with

```
^M  
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

the following simply gives me all my php files, but when I open one of them with `vim` I can't find the `^M`:

```
grep -ro "^M" /var/www/*
```

Comment: open the file in vim, and search by pressing `/Ctrl-V Enter`

Comment: `E486: Pattern not found: ^M`

Comment: Are you sure your grep can find `^M` (Ctrl-v Enter (or ctrl-M)), but same file vim cannot find that char?  are you on linux box?

Comment: Why grep wouldn't find it? I've entered `^M` with (ctrl-v ctrl-m) so it's not a combination of "^ and M"...  I'm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ^m character
:%s/^M//g

take the help from 
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/

Answer (score 0):

Try using *cat* like this:

```
head -3 *.php | cat -vet
```

You can remove all ^M like this:

```
tr -d "\r" < xxx.php > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp xxx.php
```

After backing up, you can remove all ^Ms in all *.php files like this:

```
for f in *.php; do
   tr -d "\r" < "$f" > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp "$f"
done
```

Comment: with `head -3 *.php | cat -vet` every new line is a `^M`

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so, could you accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick please? If not, please say why so that I, and others, may assist you further.